# C# interop with CUDA C dll - redux

Tags: c#, c++, dll, bitmap

Asked a few questions about a project I was working on, got some good feedback and made some progress. The idea is to create an application that generates images of fractals, accelerated by CUDA. I am creating the ui in C# and having a DLL do the heavy lifting.

Basically, I am allocating a byte array in C#, passing that to the dll to fill with pixel data, and then using that to create a Bitmap and display that with a Windows Forms PictureBox in the ui. Previous questions have helped - was using dll to allocate memory before, now using consistent calling convention between dll and c#, but the code still gives an System.ArgumentException at "img = new Bitmap(...)

Relevant Code:

C++

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl generateBitmap(void *bitmap)
{
int width = 1920;
int height = 1080;
int *dev_bmp;

gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_bmp, (3*width*height*sizeof(int))));

kernel<<<BLOCKS_PER_GRID, THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(dev_bmp, width, height);
gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(bitmap, dev_bmp, (width*height*3), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
cudaFree(dev_bmp);
}
```

c#

```
    public unsafe class NativeMethods
{

    [DllImport(@"C:\Users\Bill\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\FractalMaxUnmanaged\Debug\FractalMaxUnmanaged.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void generateBitmap(void *bitmap);

    public static Bitmap create()
    {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1920 * 1080 * 3];
        fixed (void* pBuffer = buf)
        {
            generateBitmap(pBuffer);

        }
        IntPtr unmanagedPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buf.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(buf, 0, unmanagedPtr, buf.Length);
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(1920, 1080, 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, unmanagedPtr);

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPtr);

        return img;
    }
}
```

//...

```
private unsafe void mandlebrotButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FractalBox1.Image = (Image)NativeMethods.create();
}
```

What am I still doing wrong? As far as I can tell, all the parameters are invalid, but I get an invalid parameter exception in System.Drawing when I try to create the bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what happens exactly in your case cause you didn't specify which parameter is invalid in the exception. I see that your stride must not be correct.

> stride  Type: System.Int32
>
> Integer that specifies the byte offset between the beginning of one
>   scan line and the next. This is usually (but not necessarily) the
>   number of bytes in the pixel format (for example, 2 for 16 bits per
>   pixel) multiplied by the width of the bitmap. The value passed to this
>   parameter must be a multiple of four..

So your constructor should be like this:

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(1920, 1080, 1920 * 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, unmanagedPtr);
```